# Receiving Express response in HTML and processing

Tags: html, reactjs, express, axios

I have created a MERN app and an html interface for website . I connected the HTML login form to node server successfully and received response on successful login.
after successful response I want redirection to dashboard hosted in react . can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use location.replace() in order to redirect the website to another page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).